# Meaning of "richtig" in "nicht richtig Deutsch können"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I looked up the word "richtig" in Duden and I'm not sure which meaning applies in the following sentence:

> Er kann nicht **richtig** Deutsch.

Does it mean "fehlerlos" as explained in [Definition 1b](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/richtig_fehlerfrei_passend_wahr#Bedeutung1b) or is it more like [Definition 2b](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/richtig_fehlerfrei_passend_wahr#Bedeutung2b) which is "den Erwartungen entsprechend; wie es sich gehört; ordentlich"?

Comment: Definition 2b is what is meant in this case... This obviously implies that is is not "fehlerlos".

Comment: Although the two do overlap somehow … make too many errors and you won't fulfill the expectations anymore @Gerhard.

Comment: @Jan: That's exactly what I am saying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of hard to see, but it works best when replacing *Deutsch* with something else you can learn like:

> Er kann nicht richtig rechnen.
>   Er kann nicht richtig durchschlafen.
>   Er kann sich nicht richtig aufregen.

Especially the last two can't be done with any errors, so it has to be *fulfilling the expectations*.

---

However, I would be careful classifying *richtig* as an adjective in this context. If it were an adjective for *Deutsch*, then it would need to be inflicted:

> Er kann kein **richtiges** Deutsch.

But it isn't (and the sentence is still correct). Hence I would classify it as an adverb. See also the examples above which all have a verb and not a noun following *richtig*. The Duden entry for the adverb *richtig* talks about a different meaning, though.

Comment: Dictionaries don't usually make a clear distinction between German adverbs and adjectives because they are often identical in form. Even though it says "adjective" in the dictionary, it doesn't mean it can't be used as an adverb as clearly seen from the examples provided by Duden.